# How to filter data by string

Tags: pandas, filter

Please, it would be great if someone gives me a clue as to resolve my willing to filter data with str 'Трафик с мобильных устройств'. 
Now, if I run this code:

```
data.query('Segment == Трафик с мобильных устройств')
```

I'll get this message:
 Segment ==Трафик с мобильных устройств
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

If do this:

```
data[data['Segment] == Трафик с мобильных устройств']
```

I will get:
data[data['Segment] == Трафик с мобильных устройств']

I have:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr7qE.png)

I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzp0c.png)

Comment: Sorry, I have done a mistake. In the second case, I will get this message "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `""`, if first `'`:

```
data.query('Segment == "Трафик с мобильных устройств"')
#alternative with swapped " -> '
#data.query("Segment == 'Трафик с мобильных устройств'")
```

For second:

```
data[data['Segment'] == 'Трафик с мобильных устройств']
#alternative
#data[data["Segment"] == "Трафик с мобильных устройств"]
```

**Sample**:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Segment':['Трафик с мобильных устройств',
                                'Трафик',
                                'Трафик с мобильных устройств']})

df = data.query('Segment == "Трафик с мобильных устройств"')
print (df)
                        Segment
0  Трафик с мобильных устройств
2  Трафик с мобильных устройств

df = data[data['Segment'] == 'Трафик с мобильных устройств']
print (df)
                        Segment
0  Трафик с мобильных устройств
2  Трафик с мобильных устройств
```

Comment: @ ezraelcool, but if I run this I got it UndefinedVariableError: name 'Segment' is not defined, the same the second KeyError: 'Segment'

Comment: @Andrew - It is not column name? what is `print (data.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: ['Category', 'Month', 'Segment ', 'Revenue', 'Quantity ', 'Average_price', 'Average_quantity']

Comment: @Andrew - Added sample data, for me working perfectly.

Comment: @ ezrael Got it, I have a space in 'Segment ', it works ) Thank you!!!